# cant send a message to a specific channel

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a simple dc bot, code goes like this. I tried to simplfy it to make it more readable

```
    const client = new Discord.Client();
    ...
    client.on('ready', () => {
    client.channels.cache.get('315445287374028800').send("works here");
});
    setInterval(( () =>{
    try{
        removeHTML(downloadHTML);

    } catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
}),30000);
    ...
    ...
    let removeHTML = function(callback){
    client.channels.cache.get('315445287374028800').send("WORKS HERE");
    readHTML();
    ...
}
let readHTML = function(){
    console.log("dolar is read");
    //client.channels.cache.get('315445287374028800').send("DOESNT WORK HERE");

    fs.readFile(dir + '/index.html' , 'utf-8', function(err,html){
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        else{
            //client.channels.cache.get('315445287374028800').send("DOESNT WORK HERE");
            if(isPeak){
                //client.channels.cache.get('315445287374028800').send("DOESNT WORK HERE");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

seems like send function doesnt work in callback functions but how can i fix this?

Error type: same error for all ("DOESNT WORK HERE") lines :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
   at readHTML (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Discord Bot\index.js:142:18)
   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Discord Bot\index.js:182:1)
   at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
   at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
   at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain]
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with the callback, it seems that the channel ID is incorrect or uncached. For future reference, "doesn't work" is not enough for us to go by. What happens? Do you get any errors?

Comment: updated the post @Lioness100

Comment: Alright, thanks! And I take back what I said in the first post, I misunderstood what was happening in the code and didn't realize you were using the same channel IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have turned all functions to async-await instead and it worked